# PHP isn't working with xampp/apache

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, xampp

As said in the title, php isn't working with xampp/apache where all my other files (html/css/js) works well.
Is there a problem with my php calls, or in php code itself ?
My configuration is that the path in httpd.conf and httpd_vhosts.conf are for a folder in desktop;
My php calls in my html file (with ajax) are that :

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/add_events.php',
    data: {'title': eventData.title,'start': eventData.start.format() ,'end': eventData.end.format() ,'areHere':eventData.areHere,'finalConsult':eventData.finalConsult },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: './php/update_events.php',
    data: {'title': $(this).data('calEvent').title,'start': $(this).data('calEvent').start ,'end': $(this).data('calEvent').end ,'areHere':$(this).data('calEvent').areHere,'finalConsult':$(this).data('calEvent').finalConsult ,'id': $(this).data('calEvent').id },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: './php/remove_events.php',
    data: {'id':$(this).data('id')} ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
events: './php/events.php'
```

Note that i'm using fullcalendar (based on jquery) and that the "remove_events.php" call is the only one that returns me a "OK" as alert.
Notify me if i have to post the php codes and i'll edit that post.
Thanks you in advance !

EDIT : I want to precise that each one of those ajax calls are snippets and aren't the full code

EDIT 2 : There's no error message in the browser's console and network tab and they're now all returning an "OK" as alert

EDIT 3 : Here's the php code for add_events.php, i want it to send the data received from js to my db :

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$start=$_POST['start'];
$end=$_POST['end'];
$areHere=$_POST['areHere'];
$finalConsult=$_POST['finalConsult'];
$typeConsult=$_POST['typeConsult'];
try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agenda', 'root', '');
} catch(Exception $e) {
 exit('Connexion failed');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (ID_evenement,Nom_patient,Nom_groupe,Type_consultation,Heure_debut,Heure_fin,Consulte_finale,Presence,ID_client,ID_groupe,ID_observe) VALUES ('',:title, '', :typeConsult, :start, :end, :finalConsult, :areHere, '', '','')";

$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':typeConsult'=>$typeConsult ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end, ':finalConsult'=>$finalConsult, ':areHere'=>$areHere));

?>
```

EDIT 4 : When i try to open the php file in browser or to echo some infomations from php, it sends a 404-like error

Comment: well php is server side wher as html/css/js is client side

Comment: URL's never look like file paths beginning dot slash. `./`

Comment: Well if you are working with **xampp** you hsould put your sites folder inside **htdocs** why are you putting them in your Desktop ?

Comment: I know but xampp allows me to create a kind of "local server" right ? @rtfm

Comment: @teeyo because that's much more convenient and we can edit the working path

Comment: @delboy1978uk how they must look like so ?

Comment: if one of them's working but the others aren't, then either you're pointing the others to the wrong location, or they have bugs. What HTTP status are you getting back when you call those "not working" URLs? I see your javascript code isn't checking for errors (via the ajax "error" callback), so you'll have to check your browser's console and/or network tab to see what response you're getting. That'll give us a clue as to what the problem is. "Not working" could mean 1000 different things. Specific error messages would be a lot more useful.

Comment: @ADyson There's no error in the browser's console (if they'd have, i'd say it), and now, with right path, all ajax calls send the alert

Comment: ok so probably they were returning 404 before - did you check the network tab? You can get HTTP errors from there too.

Comment: ok but how can i access that ?

Comment: in your developer tools same as the console. Click the "network" tab in there. Then you can see all requests taking place in the lifetime of the page, you can see what the browser sent to the server, and what response was received.

Comment: Ok, i watched at it and there's no error too

Comment: so it's working now? What statuses are returned by the ajax calls? 200? or something else?

Comment: 200 but it's not working

Comment: 200 means the script was called, PHP ran and had no errors, and sent the response

Comment: ok so look inside the call. What was in the response? Anything? If it returned 200 but doesn't display the alert then I would guess that possibly the response data was invalid in some way.

Comment: but it stills doesn't work...However, in the php there's only a db connexion with data sent (and i set a try catch on db connexion so it works) but in the db, there's nothing new and the alert works

Comment: What's "not working" then? The HTTP request is fine. So what do you mean? Like I said earlier "Not working" is a completely meaningless phrase. We can't tell you _anything_ based on that statment. Be _specific_ and _precise_ about what is, or is not, happening. If there's a problem with the logic in the PHP script...well we can't fix that because we can't see it.

Comment: So here's my code for add_events.php :
`<?php
 
$title=$_POST['title'];
$start=$_POST['start'];
$end=$_POST['end'];
$areHere=$_POST['areHere'];
$finalConsult=$_POST['finalConsult'];
$typeConsult=$_POST['typeConsult'];
 
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agenda', 'root', '');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
 exit('Connexion failed.');
 }
 
$sql = "[some insert into sql query]";

$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);

$q->execute(array([variable to string]));

?>
`

Comment: and for precision, anything is happening when the php script is launched apart the "OK" alert

Comment: edit the question with that code please and format it properly. That's a barely-readable stream of text. And then please tell us what you expect it to do. You can of course also debug this yourself by echoing variables at various points to see where the code goes and what the values are. Have you tried that? That's what I mean by being precise and specific. It's a basic skill of programming that you must be able to debug your application and find the specific place where a problem is occuring. By waiting for the output from ajax you're like a user, only looking at the symptom and not the cause

Comment: I did the edit, and for the self debugging, the try catch does it, i'll just veriy that values are sent to php

Comment: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes, this just leaves an unnecessary potential security hole. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.

Comment: ok so when i'm trying to echo some values from  php and alerts for it, it says that it doesn't find the php file @ADyson

Comment: huh? You said they all returned 200 OK. So now you get a 404 again?

Comment: and yes i know but for now, that's in local, i'll set an user when it'll be online

Comment: and no there's no 404, that's very very strange

Comment: ok... what does " says that it doesn't find the php file " mean then? What _exactly_ is happening? Again you are giving vague descriptions instead of actual details.

Comment: That says "Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging.** If you are asked for additional information, [edit] it into your question.

Comment: have you got an include / require / load statement somewhere in the PHP? sounds like it's probably not loading a required file correctly. Were there no more details in the error? Usually you get a more specific description following that part of the message. Again it could be an issue with the path being used.

Comment: @CodyGray i already edited, and if comments are not for debugging, for what does it serves ?

Comment: @ADyson after saying that it says : Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'entire path' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements." That's what it says in the box. That's what they're for. This is a Q&A site. You ask a question at the top, and you get answers at the bottom. That is breaking down here, and this has turned into an extended chain of comments, which is not what the site is for. Please take the [tour].

Comment: ok so you have some missing or incorrect paths to your files. Can't really help you with since we can't see your filesystem. You need to work out where the files you want actually are held (or install them if they're not installed) and make sure you point your PHP code to the correct place on disk. And yes Cody is right any extra info should go into the question, as I pointed out some time ago, instead of continuing to write info in comments which should be part of the provided question info.

Comment: So i'm in the rules, i just ask for more informations, like said in the tour. There's no problem and you just validated that. This question isn't answered and there's no pm system on this site so how can i do it in an other way ? please tell me, is editing 30 times better than commenting 30 times ? @CodyGray

Comment: There *is* a problem: you are abusing the comment system to have an extended discussion. Comments on the question are for people to ask you for more information. To provide that information, you [edit] the question. Yes, editing 30 times is better than leaving 30 comments. Good questions require *no* comments.

Comment: So i edited it one more time.. that isn't my fault if i get no answer and if i need it. Delete all those comment if it bothers you. I think myself in right to do this. And no, a good question _requires_ discussion.

Comment: @Y.Bernard I agree with Cody, a good question would provide all the necessary information up front. Discussion is required because you repeatedly fail to provide useful or detailed info and I have to try and drag it out of you like blood from a stone. You clearly don't understand the value of detailed info and as such I suspect you will struggle to have much success in programing. And your most recent edit again provides only very vague information and repeats what you said earlier. It hardly includes anything from the comments as you were asked to do by the moderator.

Comment: This will be my last comment on this question because it's un-answerable without enough relevant info and my attempts to get you to provide clarity have failed.

Comment: i did exactly what u asked and this is no end, so i'm waiting on other forums for an answer, thanks for all, bye. Oh and, for the success in programing, think what u want, i don't care of what you can think of it, this was much time lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem that was finally simple (that's strange that no one here pointed it).
The problem came from my path, which contained spaces and special characters, that was not accepted for the configuration of my environment. So thanks to all however.

Answer (score 1):

Fix these, those aren't URLs. It looks more like a relative file path

```
 url: './php/add_events.php',
```

You can either put the full URL including the domain:

```
url: 'http://whatever.com/path/to/add_events.php',
```

Or without:

```
url: '/path/to/add_events.php',
```

Comment: I tested it and the 3 snippets with an alert sent the alert but the php doesn't work @delboy1978uk

Comment: can you access the php script directly in the browser? even if it causes an error due to missing data? Whats the URL?

Comment: when i try to access php directly in the browser, it says that :  
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: the URL was "/php/add_events.php"

Comment: ok, so just try losing the dot from the front, right click open web inspector network panel and see what requests are made by your javascript

Comment: The request is done for add_events.php with a status of 200 (that's ok i think)

Comment: @Y.Bernard if you are using local server then your url start like `http://localhost/` then path

Comment: @AjayKumar thanks but it works with the relative url path too

Comment: @AjayKumar that's actually not great advice because then you have to re-write your code when you deploy it somewhere else (e.g. into live). Maintainability nightmare.

Comment: best just start with `/`

Comment: That's what i did

Comment: @ADyson no it not about that i am just telling him to test it is php working or not. not to telling him to change in his code.